# What does it mean if my decision tree gets bigger or doesn't get bigger with more data?

Tags: machine-learning

My understanding is that if your tree is growing still with more data it means the data being added has increased complexity hence the decision tree creates more rules ie more branches and leaves. If it was just more of the same data (no added variation) it should not grow bigger?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on the setting of stopping criteria you choose. Take a look at the documentation of [`DecisionTreeClassifier` from scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier):

> **max_depth : *int, default=None***
>
> The maximum depth of the tree. If None, then nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than
> min_samples_split samples.
>
> **min_samples_split : *int or float, default=2***
>
> The minimum number of samples required to split an internal node [...]
>
> **min_samples_leaf : *int or float, default=1***
>
> The minimum number of samples required to be at a leaf node. A split point at any depth will only be considered if it leaves at least
> `min_samples_leaf` training samples in each of the left and right
> branches. This may have the effect of smoothing the model, especially
> in regression.

Changing any of those could have effect on the depth of the tree.

On another hand, if you don't use stopping criteria, but [just prune](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443548/random-forest-pruning-vs-stopping-criteria/445221#445221) the tree after the training, than the answer would be more complicated, I'm not even sure if an easy answer exists for such question.